# Is is possible to search multiple fields in microsoft word at the same time?

Tags: microsoft-word

lets say i have quite a number of unique ids like 1891, 1173, 1256... etc and i want to search them in a word document and see if all the ids exists in the doc to find out which are those missing. Is is possible to search all at the same time rather than entering each of them into the search field each time?

Comment: I guess you mean strings, not fields.?.

Comment: What version of Word?

Comment: Xavierjazz: ya strings or text :)

Comment: Geditdk: i have both 2007 and 2013 version